# border none property does not really remove the border (visually)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I got an expected problem. I am working on the design of my application. I would like to make the border of my form field invisible. So far I've tried this:

```
 border: none;
 border-style: none;
 border-width: 0px;
```

But none of them work correctly. It's like it's changing color between gray and white but it's visible.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7FJQ.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could it be an outline instead of a border? Post your HTML also so we can help better.

Comment: change border-with to border-width

Comment: try `border:0`. maybe your form field initially got an outline. so try `outline:0` aswell

Comment: nobody mentions that there's no demo whatsoever to see the exact problem?

Comment: Short demo would be great to indentify the issue :) Or at least a screenshot of you borwser's inspector

Comment: @Alexis the image appears?

Comment: that might be having `box-shadow` try giving `box-shadow: none`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The border looks more like a drop shadow than an actual grey line. I see you've tagged the question with 'twitter-bootstrap'. Try adding the following line to your code where fit.

```
box-shadow: none;
```

Comment: A cheating way of solving the issue is also just **setting the forms border properties to the same color as the background** so it would appear invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if not working then check your box-shadow, and outline also should be none.

```
.abc{
    border:none!important;
}
```